# is AsyncLocal<object> memory safe in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use `AsyncLocal<T>`, so I should know whether it is memory-safe or not, and when it will free value memory.

My version: .NET Core 2.2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safety of AsyncLocal in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511243/safety-of-asynclocal-in-asp-net-core)